# Angular 5, what is this? (help identify misunderstood code) Use of <ng-content>

Tags: angular

I remember clearly seeing somewhere this piece of code:

```
<app-login>*some content*</app-login>
```

The app-login is a regular component that was used in the project, but what amazed me was the content between the opening and closing tag,
when I tried to replicate it did nothing...
what is the content between the selectors? what can I do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you write in between `<app-login>` & `</app-login>` will go to `<ng-content>` tag of component here `app-login`

**login.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: `app-login`,
    template: `<div><h2>Enter your credentials:</h2></div>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})
export class LoginComponent {

}
```

suppose you are using `<app-login>` as following

```
<app-login>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
    </div>
</app-login>
```

it means it will be computed as:

```
<div><h2>Enter your credentials:</h2></div>
// ====ng-content-block====
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
</div>
// ====ng-content-block====
```

You can also refer [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content) for detailed explanation.

> Note: `<ng-content select="...">` is pretty powerful as well. You can add multiple 'templates' and decide what component goes where.

Comment: Note: `<ng-content select="...">` is pretty powerful as well. You can add multiple 'templates' and decide what component goes where.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, under the hood, the `app-login` projects content into it's own template using the `ng-content`([Example](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b)).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.